# Should papers under review be listed in CV?

Tags: career-path, cv, assistant-professor

First, I know this question has been asked already [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/148648/about-listing-papers-under-review-in-your-cv) but was never answered.

I am applying for an assistant professorship position (in CS) and due to overloaded teaching duties over the last years, I did not produce many papers. Currently, I am trying to compensate for this by submitting a lot of papers, which are under review. In my CV, I want to show the selection committee that I am actively working on research and actively submitting papers by listing these papers but I am not sure how they will be considered.

If you were a member of the committee, how would you receive this?

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist Actually yes! Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Obviously, we cannot predict how any individual committee member will react to this. However, I think it is quite common to list 'in review' papers on a CV. Two caveats:

- If the number of 'in review' papers seems unusually high (compared to your past output, and submission/review rates typical for your field) people may start to wonder whether these are serious submissions, or if you've just fired off a load of half-baked stuff in order to pad your CV.
- If it's on your CV, you should be prepared to talk about it during interview. Having to tell the interview panel that no, none of those papers have come out yet, in fact they've all been rejected, is not going to come across well. Personally, I would only include stuff that I'm reasonably confident will progress smoothly through the review process.

Comment: Op: You can mitigate the potential negative impact by clearly separate them from the rest of the list. Moreover, within the CV main body, you could write something about. Saying something like, rough example given, "this new approach seems promising and already resulted in # submitted papers currently under review" seems better than saying nothing at all.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience I say that chances are it won't hurt and it won't help much either. There's no reason not to do it (if clearly marked as "under review") but don't expect it to make much of a difference.