# Adding papers under review on the CV when applying to CS PhD programs in the US

Tags: graduate-admissions, united-states, computer-science, cv, undergraduate

**Background:** CS undergrad applying to CS PhD Programs in Fall 2022 in the US.

The question "[Should papers under review be listed in CV?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/167540/should-papers-under-review-be-listed-in-cv)" talks about multiple "under review" papers being put on the CV.

Do answers there apply for undergrads applying for PhD programs as well?

**Context:** I have 7 papers under review while I send out my applications but all the papers will be backed by my letter writers. I also have a few publications before this *which have been published*.

Comment: You have seven papers under review plus some already published?! I don't think having any papers under review matters in this particular instance. It's field dependent of course, but I got a postdoc with only two papers to my name, never mind a PhD. Are the papers under review on arXiv or similar?

Comment: Oh alright, thank you for that! They are all under review and part of grants so I am not allowed to post them on arXiv because the grants are technically not under my name!

Answer (score 2):

"Under review" is better than "Pending" or "In progress".

I would include them, but be clear.  In some cases, it is appropriate to list the journal because there was a review and there are comments to address, in other cases, if you submit and have gotten nothing back, I'd recommend just listing "Under review".

Comment: Thank you for this answer, I just listed all the papers under review in a separate section and the published papers in a separate section.